# Ajuda com jQuery. em calculo de parcelas!

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoal, estou com uma questão um pouco complicada para mim que sou iniciante.. estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde o usuário pode selecionar a quantidade de parcelas que deseja dividir a sua compra.. até ai ok.. porem foi solicitado um campo onde o usuário pode digitar o valor que ele pode pagar por parcela.. e ao preencher automaticamente ele deve identificar qual o valor que dividido por 12 chega mais próximo do valor preenchido. tenho o seguinte código até o momento...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Aqui ele pega o valor do campo "Você pode pagar.." -> aqui que preciso de ajuda!
        $('#parcelaAprox').change(function() {
            console.log($('#parcelaAprox').val());

            console.log($('#PrecoManager').val().replace(',', '.') / 12);

            $.each(test, function (index, item) {
                console.log(index);
            });

        });

        // Aqui ao carregar a página como padrão o valor de parcelas é 12
        var vParcela = $('#PrecoManager').val().replace(',', '.') / $('#nParcelas').val();
        vParcela = parseFloat(vParcela).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
        $('#vParcela').html(vParcela);

        // Aqui ele divide o valor do produto pela quantidade de parcelas selecionadas
        $('#nParcelas').change(function () {
            var vParcela = $('#PrecoManager').val().replace(',', '.') / $('#nParcelas').val();
            vParcela = parseFloat(vParcela).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
            $('#vParcela').html(vParcela);
        });

    });
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo baseado nos seus campos de como deve se comportar.

Basicamente usei duas variáveis para comparar o valor digitado e armazenar a menor ocorrência entre as parcelas. Também adicionei um Array para armazenar as parcelas e facilitar a comparação.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Valor do produto para teste
 let ValorTotal = 5000.00;
  
    let eParcelas = $("#qtdParcelas");
    let parcelas = [];
  
  for(let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
   let option = $('<option>');
    let valorParcela = ValorTotal/i
   eParcelas.append(option.attr('value', i).append(`${i}x Parcelas de R$ ${valorParcela.toLocaleString()}`));
    
    // Pra facilitar a comparação eu jogo as parcelas em um array;
    parcelas.push({
     qtdParcelas: i,
        valor: valorParcela
    });
  }
  
  $('#possoPagar').keyup(function(e){
   let valor = $('#possoPagar').val();
    let valorIdeal = 0;
    parcelas.forEach(function(v, i){
     if(v.valor <= valor && v.valor >= valorIdeal) {
       valorIdeal = v.valor;
       $("#valorIdeal").html(`${v.qtdParcelas}x de R$ ${v.valor}`);
               
        eParcelas.val(v.qtdParcelas);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    <label>Quanto você pode pagar?</label>
    <input type="number" name="possoPagar" id="possoPagar" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Parcelas</label>
    <select name="qtdParcelas" value id="qtdParcelas">      
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <h3>
    Valor ideal da parcela
  </h3>
  <div id="valorIdeal">
  </div>
</form>
```

Basta adaptar a lógica a sua necessidade, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Legal cara, acredito que vai ajuda.. vou analisar aqui seu código e tentar adaptar ao meu espero que funcione assim que tiver algum resultado te retorno. Obrigado!

Comment: @Drik Ok, qualquer dúvida poste nos comentários que eu tenho lhe auxiliar assim que possível. Boa sorte :)

Comment: Man, legal me ajudou.. consegui adaptar ao meu código porem acredito que na parte do if seja necessário algum ajuste, por exemplo.. tenho um produto de 1599,00 se eu digito 500 ele vai para a opção de 4x de 400 mais deveria ir para 3x de 533, pois é o valor que mais se aproxima de 500 correto? estou tentando melhorar aqui mais caso vc possa me dar alguma dica seria bom.. mais uma vez muito Obrigado! (y)

Comment: Faz um intervalo, soma 10% do valor digitado pra dar a margem. Por exemplo. 500 - 550, 300 - 330, 200 - 220, 290 - 319. Assim voce consegue aproximar mais.

Comment: Não entendi muito a lógica.. =x

Comment: O problema é que enquanto ele é menor que o valor da parcela ele não reconhece aquela parcela

Answer (score 5):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = 600; // valor base do produto
  $('#valor, #nParcelas').on('change input', function(e) {
    var valor = Number($('#valor').val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.') || 0);
    var parcelas = Number($('#nParcelas').val());

    if (this.id == 'valor') { // caso de mudar o valor
      var match = {diff: Infinity};
      for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        var diferenca = Math.abs(total - valor * i);
        if (diferenca < match.diff) match = {i: i, diff: diferenca};
      }

      $('#nParcelas').val(parcelas = match.i);
      if (parcelas * valor < total) return $('#vParcela').text('O valor é demasiado baixo...');
    }

    $('#valor').val((valor = (total / parcelas)));
    $('#vParcela').text('R$ ' + (total / parcelas).toLocaleString('pt-br'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Total: R$600</p>
<input id="valor" />
<select id="nParcelas" value="12">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option selected>12</option>
</select>
<select id="vVencimento">
  <option value="1">Dia 1</option>
  <option value="2">Dia 2</option>
  <option value="3">Dia 3</option>
  <option value="4">Dia 4</option>
  <option value="5">Dia 5</option>
  <option value="6">Dia 6</option>
  <option value="7">Dia 7</option>
  <option value="8">Dia 8</option>
  <option value="9">Dia 9</option>
  <option value="10" selected>Dia 10</option>
</select>
<span id="vParcela"></span>
```